# How to get environment variable Name

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I have user call 'amsd' which path is 'C:\Users\amsd'. After that I changed the user name to 'other'. But the path is not changed, its name is same as before. But now what I am trying to do is, I need to access that path from my current user. Lets assume that I know only the user name (other) not the path variable name (c:\users\amsd). But I need to access that path. How can I do that. I tried `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("other");`
But its reutrning null value

Comment: What do you mean by "changed the user name"? Do you change the logged on user or only his name? Do you want the profile path of the currently logged on user (the user that executes your app) or for a given user name?

Comment: There is [GetUserProfileDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762280(v=vs.85).aspx) which you could call via P/Invoke. But you'd have to pass a user handle which would require you to actually authenticate as that user, i.e., entering a password. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with only a user name or SID. You could perhaps enumerate subfolders of `C:\Users` and look at their ACLs to determine which one belongs to the user in question.

Comment: @Joey do u ave any code related to this in c#. i searched for that method but I found code in c++. or can you mention some links

Answer (score 0):

I have username. So what i did is passing my username as parameter to NTAccount constructor and getting sid of user. below is the code.

```
NTAccount f = new NTAccount(username);
SecurityIdentifier s  = (SecurityIdentifier)f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
string sid = s.ToString();
```

after that using that sid i am getting profile folder by reading the value from registry using below path.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\sid
```

under that path there is key call profileimagepath there i can get the user profile pat